# Overflow while calculating combinations

Tags: c++

I am trying to calculate the combination C(40, 20) in C++, however the data types in C++ seems unable to correctly handle this calculation even though I have used `long long` data type. The following is my code:

```
#include <iostream>

long long fac(int x) {
    register long long i,f = 1; // Optimize with regFunction
    for(i = 1;i <= x;i++)
        f *= i;
    std::cout << f << std::endl;
    return f;
}

// C(n,r) = n!/r!(n-r)!
long long C(long long n, long long r) {
    return fac(n) / (fac(r) * fac(n - r));
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    std::cout << C(40, 20) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Any idea to solve this problem?

Comment: Ummm.... don't you mean `C(40, 20)`? The other way around doesn't make sense. How can you choose 40 samples from a group of 20?

Comment: 1. find a way to do your calculation using smaller values, OR 2. find a way to calculate with less precision and use `double`, OR 3. use a bignum library.

Comment: @CoryKramer, Thanks I've revised it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Compute C at once by executing division immediately after multiplication:

```
long long C(long long n, long long r) 
{
    long long f = 1; // Optimize with regFunction
    for(auto i = 0; i < r;i++)
        f = (f * (n - i)) / (i + 1);
    return f ; 
}
```

Result should be exact (divisions without remainders, until overflows) since any integer factor present in (i+1) is already present in (n -i). (Should not be too difficult to prove)

Answer (score 3):

Your numbers are growing too much and that is a common problem in this kind of calculations and I am afraid there is no straightforward solution. Even if you might reduce a bit the number of multiplications you will make probably still you will end up in an overflow with `long long`

You might want to check those out:

https://mattmccutchen.net/bigint/

https://gmplib.org/

I know there are different algorithmic approaches on this matter. I remember there were some solutions to use strings to store integer representations and stuff but as @Konrad mentioned this might be a poor approach to the matter.

Comment: Using strings to store the numbers is just a poor-man’s bignum library. It has no advantage over using better libraries.

Comment: yeah that could be true I am not sure about that part as I have mentioned. But I will edit it to make it a bit more clear.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that factorials get big very quickly. 40! is too large to be stored in a `long long`. Luckily you don’t actually need to compute this number here since you can reduce the fraction in the calculation of `C(n, r)` before computing it. This yields the equation (from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination#Number_of_k-combinations)):

[image: reduced combination formula]

This works much better since *k*! (*r*! in your code) is a much smaller number than *n*!. However, at some point it will also break down.

Alternatively, you can also use the recurrence definition by implementing a recursive algorithm. However, this will be **very** inefficient (exponential running time) unless you memoise intermediate results.

Comment: That's write, as long as `k < 21`

Comment: @Thomas True; I’ve added a slight clarification.

Answer (score 2):

A lazy way out would be to use a library that supports multiple precision, for example [GNU GMP](https://gmplib.org/).

Once you have installed it correctly (available from the repositories on most Linux distributions), it comes down to:

- adding `#include <gmpxx.h>` to your source file
- replacing `long long` with `mpz_class`
- compiling with `-lgmpxx -lgmp`

The source:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <gmpxx.h>

mpz_class fac(mpz_class x) {
    int i;
    mpz_class f(1); // Optimize with regFunction
    for(i = 1;i <= x;i++)
        f *= i;
    std::cout << f << std::endl;
    return f;
}

// C(n,r) = n!/r!(n-r)!
mpz_class C(mpz_class n, mpz_class r) {
    return fac(n) / (fac(r) * fac(n - r));
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    std::cout << C(40, 20) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Compiling and running:

```
$ g++ comb.cpp -lgmpxx -lgmp -o comb
$ ./comb
2432902008176640000
2432902008176640000
815915283247897734345611269596115894272000000000
137846528820
```

If you want to be thorough, you can do a lot more, but this will get you answers.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you used uint64 aka ulonglong, the max value is `18446744073709551615` whereas 40! is `815915283247897734345611269596115894272000000000` which is *a bit* bigger.

I recommend you to use [GMP](https://gmplib.org/) for this kind of maths